# Can VCS output a shared library instead of an executable (simv)?

Tags: shared-libraries, fpga, system-verilog, riscv, synopsys-vcs

We've a C++ application intended to be run on a x86 hosted RISC-V processor. The application is executed on both the host (x86) and the tethered RISC-V processor. The RISC-V processor is emulated on an FPGA. We have a shared library called `libfpga_intf.so` consisting of drivers providing a C API to the RISC-V processor on the FPGA.

We also wish to simulate the RISC-V processor on VCS, as access to FPGA system is limited. I've systemverilog models of the RISC-V processor and the FPGA interface which I'd like to compile with the C++ application. Is there a way I could compile the SV models with VCS to generate `libfpga_intf.so` equivalent.

(I could use SV DPI to compile application into VCS `simv`, which means the application executable is `simv` and command line interface is very different to what is actually intended by the application. I prefer the software interface to be a drop in replacement to the real FPGA system.)

Comment: There used to be a `slave` simulation mode in vcs-mx which was used in similar applications. There is no description of it in documentation. Check with https://solvnet.synopsys.com/ or ask synopsys directly.

Comment: Thanks @Serge! That seems like the one I'm looking for.. I'll try it out!